# Duplicating server : HOWTO get and install the exact / same RPM packages?

Tags: backup, rpm

Good morning,

Quite often, I need to create a backup server from a original server ( Rocky9). I have, thanks to Webmin, the exact configuration, but the original server got specific RPM packages installed ( while building and tuning it ) and to qo quick, if I had a list of all the RPM installed or a way to install a backup server with the same OS and the same RPM ( without missing one) , that could be quite efficient. Then I apply my config and that should work out straight out from the box !, which is not always the case. sometimes I can spend hours and hours, because one package hasn't been installed..

Is there an easy way to do so ? ( to backup the OS installation config ) An RPM command or  which can generate a list of RPM package ? or an XML file, which can be used for re-installation ?

or should I find a script which list all installed packages and be able to use the another script to install the list of RPM packages ?

Thanks and regards,

looking for a way to gather RPM packages from an installation

Answer (score 0):

1. The best way - and I dare to say the industry standard - is to have an Ansible playbook that describes your setup. And then you can run your playbook just for a different machine. I have Ansible playbook for every machine. Including my working notebook. If something is important then it goes into a playbook.
2. Too enterprisy for you? Just gimme the dammned one-liner boy?

- copy content of /etc/yum.repos.d/*
- save the output of `rpm -qa` on machine A
- on machine B run: `dnf install $(cat list.from.machine.A.txt)`